# Send parameters to server (post Method) in flutter with Web View

Tags: dart, flutter

how can i send parameters To server and get response using Web View in flutter ??
I want go to my URL and get response from sever . But i want do it by Web View in flutter

Comment: If you find the answer, share the solution. Thank.

Comment: Hi If you found any solution, could you please share the solution !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67948632/1140304

Answer (score 0):

Lets make below example.

Suppose If we are calling here **login API** with required **username** and **password** as parameters.

Hope you know that we have to import below packages.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
```

And below is method that I have made it for easy understanding.

```
Future<http.Response> callWebServiceForLofinUser() async {

    final paramDic = {
      "username": 'email@example.com', 
      "password": '123456',
    };

    final loginData = await http.post(
      "http://www.xxxx.com/dev/api/user/userLogin.php",  // change with your API
      body: paramDic,
    );

    print(loginData.body);

    return loginData;
  }
```

If you have any confusion with above code then feel free to ask me.

Comment: The question was how to do this via the WebView

Answer (score -1):

This work for me.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';


final Map<String,dynamic> _login={
  "username":null,
  "password":null
};

//manually add parameters to the URL
final loginData = await http.post(
  "http://www.xxxx.com/dev/api/user/userLogin.php?username="+_login["username"]+"&password="+_login["password"],  // change with your API
  body: paramDic,
);

print(loginData.body);
```

Or Use https://pub.dev/packages/dio

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'dart:async';


final Map<String,dynamic> _login={
  "username":null,
  "password":null
};

Dio dio = new Dio();
Response response = await 
dio.post("http://www.xxxx.com/dev/api/user/userLogin.php,
queryParameters:_login,)
.then((onValue){
  print("Success $onValue");
}).catchError((onError){
  print("Error $onError");
});
```

Comment: The question was how to do this via the WebView

Comment: This is not in webview

Comment: This is not for webview.