# How to Post Data to URL in Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, post, webview

I want to post some data to the URL body in Flutter WebView.
So, how can I do it?

Comment: I can post data with the HTTP package but I want to go to an URL directly in webview with some data to its header and body.

Comment: I said I want to post data in its Body, not in Param

Comment: Why are you deleting your comments again and again!?

Comment: Do you want to do something like that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data (e.g. post data from a form or maybe js inside the body to some webservice)?

Comment: No. I need to do it with the WebView flutter package.

Comment: Well I don't understand what you are trying to do then. You can easily run javascript inside the Flutter WebView and send Post requests. Or are you trying to send a post request to the WebView (which would make no sense)?

Comment: trying to send a post request to the WebView

Comment: I see. I think you might have a misconception about what either a POST Request ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP) ) or the flutter WebView is. You can only send a post request to a http server. The flutter WebView is a component that renders HTML and executes JS, wasm, etc. but is not a HTTP Server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`webview_flutter` doesn't have a method to send post requests at this moment.
However, you can try my [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin. It supports POST requests!

A simple example using the current latest version `5.0.5+3` of the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin is:

```dart
var postData = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("firstname=Foo&lastname=Bar"));
controller.postUrl(url: Uri.parse("https://example.com/my-post-endpoint"), postData: postData);
```

where the `postData` is the Body of the request in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

For example, if you have a PHP server, you can access the `firstname` and `lastname` values as you normally would do, that is `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['lastname']`.

You can also initialize the `InAppWebView` widget with an initial POST request like this:

```dart
child: InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
    url: Uri.parse("https://example.com/my-post-endpoint"),
    method: 'POST',
    body: Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("firstname=Foo&lastname=Bar")),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    
  },
),
```

Comment: Could this package post 'form-data' type also? seems only url-encoded.

Comment: It replace `+' with space while doing Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("username=Foo&password=Bar+//ede+")), Can you please help how I can avoid this? I want to send data in form

Answer (score 7):

You can run JS functions on official Flutter [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) ::

1-Example of Post request by JS

```
**
 * sends a request to the specified url from a form. this will change the window location.
 * @param {string} path the path to send the post request to
 * @param {object} params the parameters to add to the url
 * @param {string} [method=post] the method to use on the form
 */

function post(path, params, method='post') {

  // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
  // It can be made less verbose if you use one.
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  form.method = method;
  form.action = path;

  for (const key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
      hiddenField.name = key;
      hiddenField.value = params[key];

      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

2-Convert JS function to a String in Flutter and Call that

```
final String postUrl="'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'";
final String postParam= "{name: 'Johnny Bravo'}";
final String requestMethod= "'post'";

final  String jsFunc="function post(path, params, method='post') {"+
    "const form = document.createElement('form');"+
    "form.method = method;"+
    "form.action = path;"+
    "for (const key in params) {"+
    "if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {"+
    "const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');"+
    "hiddenField.type = 'hidden';"+
    "hiddenField.name = key;"+
    "hiddenField.value = params[key];"+
    "form.appendChild(hiddenField);}}document.body.appendChild(form);form.submit();}"+
    "post($postUrl, $postParam, method=$requestMethod)";
```

3- Run JS code in WebView

```
return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
    future: _controller.future,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
      if (controller.hasData) {
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            controller.data!.evaluateJavascript(jsFunc);
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.call_received),
        );
      }
      return Container();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

the question was created a long time ago, but I found a new way

In [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) add new function)

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: item.url,
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  debuggingEnabled: false,
  onWebResourceError: (error) {
    debugPrint(error.domain);
  },
  zoomEnabled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    controller.loadRequest(
      WebViewRequest(
        uri: Uri.parse("YOUR URL"),
        headers: "YOUR MAP<STRING, STRING>",
        method: WebViewRequestMethod.post,
        body: Uint8List.fromList(
          utf8.encode(
            jsonEncode("YOUR MAP<STRING, DYNAMIC>"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Just if someone gets here with the same problem as I did, finally I made this work like this:
body: Uint8List.fromList('param=paramValue&anotherParam=paramValue'.codeUnits)
And remember that if you are giving urls as a parameter they must be encoded!

Comment: @PabloNicolasOshiroMondoñedo can you please explain your comment with example because I am facing same issue I am sending hash is body and `+` is replaced by space.I try with `Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode((Uri.encodeQueryComponent(Get.arguments))))` but this way I am not able to send payload as form.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked ,I found a way to pass form data as body .I have used flutter  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

```
          url: Uri.parse(POS_URL),
          method: 'POST',
          body: Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode('input_data=${jsonEncode(jsonPayload)}')),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        ),
```

Comment: I need to achieve this in flutter webAPP

FYI: flutter_inappwebview does not have support for web

Any Suggestion to achieve this on webAPP!

Answer (score 0):

for me applied html form auto submission post request as below

Create an HTML file that contains the form you want to submit automatically.

and then You can load the HTML content into a Flutter WebView using the InAppWebView widget from the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
    
    class WebViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        String htmlContent = """
          <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Auto Submit Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="https://example.com/submit" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1">
        <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2">
    </form>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
        """;
    
        return InAppWebView(
          initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: htmlContent),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of above approach. Nothing help me to solve my problem. I have been trying to implement Barclaycard payment gateway integration.
i just add this line and solve my problem using [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

```
Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(payLoad.replaceAll(" ", "+")))
```

here payload is string like

```
payload="param1=data1&parma2=data&...."
```

This is my full implementation

```
body: InAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
        url: Uri.parse(
            "https://payments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/orderstandard.asp"),
        method: 'POST',
        body: Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(payLoad.replaceAll(" ", "+"))),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```